# set specific column when exporting dataframe with openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Im trying to export an existing DataFrame to an xlsx file using openpyxl.

```
sql = text('''SELECT * FROM XXX''')
db = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host/dbname")
df = pd.read_sql(sql, db)
wb = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
ws = wb["base"]
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):      
    ws.append(r)
wb.save("pandas_openpyxl.xlsx")
```

That give me this

[image]

And if I put a formula in the template the same code give me this

[image]

But what I want is this

[image]

But I dont know how set the formula in the code with the value of the loop or set the default column to write the values(with formula in template)

Comment: If you prepend the formulae to the row before you append it, you can use append. Otherwise you'll need to write the cells one by one using an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Solved from

```
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):      
    ws.append(r)
```

to

```
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    ws.cell(row=r_idx+1, column=1, value="=VLOOKUP(B" + str(r_idx+1) + ",'client'!C1:D45,2,0)")
    ws.cell(row=r_idx+1, column=2, value="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L" + str(r_idx+1) + ",'client'!B:C,2,0),I" + str(r_idx+1) + ")")
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 3):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx+1, column=c_idx, value=value)
```

In this way I can set a desired formula in the loop and select start the write in desired column